# Mapstruct - Ignore property inside a collection

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have the following:

```
public class RegimenEntity {
   private Set<RegimenDrugEntity> regimenDrugs;
   ...
}

public class RegimenDrugEntity {
   private int id;
   ...
}

@Mapper
public interface RegimenMapper {
   @Mapping(target = "regimenDrugs.id", ignore = true)
   public abstract RegimenEntity entityToEntity(RegimenEntity regimenEntity)
}
```

I want to ignore the id for ALL the RegimenDrugEntity objects inside the regimenDrugs Set in RegimenEntity.

This `@Mapping(target = "regimenDrugs.id", ignore = true)` does not compile.

Comment: I think more information on the issue is needed. What is the context in which the `id` should be ignored? I.e. what is being told to ignore the id? the Set?. An example of the code that is incorrectly using the `id` may help clarify the question.

Comment: @Arbiterofbuffoonery I want to ignore the id always for all the elements in regimenDrugs Set. The code is not incorrectly using the `id`, is the `@Mapping` what is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Mapper
public interface RegimenMapper {
   @Mapping(target = "regimenDrugs.id", ignore = true)
   public abstract RegimenEntity entityToEntity(RegimenEntity regimenEntity)
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, that's what I actually tried but typed it wrong in the question. I have updated the question.

Comment: Try to create a DTO without ID. As map struct is the source-code-generated tool it needs to know to/from/how you will map your data in advance. In your case when you map RegimenDrugEntity -> RegimenDrugEntity I don't see how it's possible to exclude some property.